# How to change SVN repository to use trunk/branches/tags structure and switch working copies to it

Tags: svn

My current repository is : **/var/www/svn/project**.all my files within project folder.it doesn't have trunk,branches,tags structure as of now. Now i have created new project as **"/var/www/svn/projectnew"** with trunk,branches,tags. I took the Dump of **"/var/www/svn/project"** and loaded to **"/var/www/svn/projectnew/trunck"** and created one branch in **"/var/www/svn/projectnew/branches/site1"** from trunk.

Currently my Working copy pointing **"/var/www/svn/project"**. i tried to switch my working copy from "/var/www/svn/project" to **"/var/www/svn/projectnew/branches/site1"** but it saying,

*Repository UUID 'd3f06af7-c344-2d45-b1bd-7799e0e99d7a' doesn't match expected UID 'f5f9f6ac-3f50-7e4d-a9d4-0bc9a9b443b8'.*

Help me on how i can go with this?

Comment: How did you tool Dump of project? If you just did copy paste then your repository is going to point old project. You need to first remove SVN binding and to do that you need to export code, if your are using Tortoise SVN then it's quite easy.

Comment: I used below command for do this, $ svnadmin dump /var/www/svn/project > project.dump , $ svnadmin load /var/www/svn/projectnew/trunck --parent-dir trunk < project.dump.
Is there anything wrong in this? please advice.

Answer (score 8):

ORIGINAL REPLY:

There are two things you can do here - one is to copy the file `db/uuid` from the old server to the new one if you're just transferring the svn repository to a new machine and you plan to turn off the old one.  The other thing depends on the SVN version you're using. If you're using 1.7 then use `svn relocate` (see [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html)), or for older clients use the `--relocate` option of the `svn switch` command which is intended for this scenario.

EDIT:

I misunderstood -- you want to recreate your repository with the trunk/branches/tags structure.  In that case, dumping and reloading the project won't help as it won't magically create the new structure -- it'll just recreate what you already have.  You can though easily create the new structure either in the repository browser (if you're using TortoiseSVN) or directly from your working copy.  If you're doing it from the command line the syntax will be something like this, depending on the exact directory structure. Replace `http:.../` with the address of your svn server.  Oh, and **back up the repository first!**

```
# check out top-level directory
svn co http://.../
# make new trunk dir and move all contents to it -- note spelling of 'trunk'
mkdir trunk
svn add trunk
svn mv * trunk

# now create tags and branches
mkdir tags
mkdir branches
svn add trunk tags branches

svn commit -m "Created new repository layout"
```

Now all you should need to do to switch existing working copies over is:

```
svn switch http://.../project  http://.../trunk/project
```

Comment: Am not using new server. the old repository and new repository in same server and same root folder only (Old : /var/www/svn/project , New : /var/www/svn/projectnew/). the reason for transferring the repository is my old repo doesn't have trunk,branches structure.so that only am creating new repository with trunk,branches structure and trying to switch my WC to branch in new repo.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Thanks.The above steps for changing the current svn structure and switching between sub folders.i have checked this it is working fine.
If i want to do it in new repository, is it possible?

Comment: You can do this in a new repository, but I don't understand why you need to do so, since you can create the structure you need in the original repository.

Comment: The reason is, same application working in different site.so all are using same svn repository .so if i change directly in current SVN repository may be some problem will occur.so that only i want to put it in new repository.

Comment: This worked great for me with one small change. Since trunk was added in the first svn add, the second svn add should only include tags and branches, not trunk. `svn add tags branches` which will prevent "svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned"

Comment: The command `svn mv * trunk` doesn't work for me, because `*` includes `trunk`, so I get an error because the folder cannot be moved into itself. I'm using Subversion 1.8.8. It seems like using `svn mv !(trunk) trunk/` would work, but then I get another error when svn tries to move unversioned folders, matched by `*` or `!(trunk)` but unknown to svn.

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to keep history as it is and switch to the new structure starting from a new revision. In this case you will not need dump/load manipulations with repository.

1. "svn delete" everything from repository root
2. create trunk/branches/tags structure
3. "svn copy" repository content from revision before deleting to trunk